# Unreal Engine 5 - Problem with importing FBX

Tags: blender, unreal-engine4, fbx, unreal-engine5

I've recently made a character with Blender and rigged with AccuRig, and when I import the FBX model of my character into UE5, the character seem "transparant" (look the screens). [In UE5 when importing with the default settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iI5Z.png)
I've checked some tutorials to import FBX proprely but nothing changes : The FBX import is still weird.
My FBX seems to be normal when i put it in blender. [Blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gOJn.png)
Any ideas ?

-> Watch tutorials on FBX in UE5